# How to align image

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

If i have in my beamer presentation some list of items and on that slide i wanna add a picture, which i want to be aligned e.g. to right top corner.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{III. Override pages}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Bookmark manager
    \item History
    \item New tab
\end{enumerate}
    % image aligned to top right corner
\end{frame}
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use one of the packages [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic), [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi), [`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) or [`everyshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi). `textpos` is easy to use, though a bit older just like `everyshi`.

Here's a way using TikZ and the `current page node` for positioning:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{III. Override pages}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Bookmark manager
    \item History
    \item New tab
\end{enumerate}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
  \node [xshift=-2cm,yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north east)
    {\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm]{file}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer example]

You could also use the node anchor for positioning besides that shifting.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [`textpos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package to place the picture in the desired position.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{III. Override pages}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Bookmark manager
      \item History
      \item New tab
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{textblock*}{20mm}(\textwidth,0mm)%
    \rule{2cm}{4cm}
  \end{textblock*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```