# Positioning using textpos and animated blocks

Tags: beamer, textpos

I am trying to position a figure on a page using `textpos` and then have a block appear over it in the next slide. I am inspired by the Gonzalo Medina's code given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13084/how-to-align-image). Here is what my code looks like, but the figure that is positioned on the page using `textpos` covers over the block as seen below -- block should cover that portion of the figure. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{III. Override pages}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Bookmark manager
      \item History
      \item New tab
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{textblock*}{20mm}(50mm,30mm)%
    \rule{2cm}{4cm}
  \end{textblock*}

  \only<2->{
    \centering
    \begin{block}{Block Title}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
     \end{block}
   }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case it's better to use `TikZ` and not `textpos` (more information in [Christian's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16362/1952) answer to [How can I position an image in an arbitrary position in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/how-can-i-position-an-image-in-an-arbitrary-position-in-beamer/16362#16362))

`textpos` manual explains that `overlay` option places the contents over anything else, so it's not possible to draw something over the rule later on because the rule is on top of each slide.

Next code using `TikZ` `remember picture` and `overlay` options worked for me in this particular case.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{III. Override pages}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Bookmark manager
      \item History
      \item New tab
  \end{enumerate}

  \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node at (current page.center) {\rule{2cm}{4cm}};

  \only<2->{
    \centering
    \begin{block}{Block Title}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
     \end{block}
   }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]